# Where do I find youtube video's that I'm playing on Ubuntu?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu-10.10

I'm using Mozilla Firefox on Ubuntu 10.10, suddenly I don't find the video I'm browsing  in "`/tmp`" nor in the browser cache "`/home/.mozilla/firefox/cache`", where else can I find the streaming video I'm browsing?

Is there any easy way to download videos from youtube.com, etc. on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

The new Flash Player no longer stores the videos in `/tmp` but in Firefox' cache, which does not allow you to extract it as easily as just copying it... You need to downgrade to an earlier Flash version (10.1.102.64 at most). Get it [here](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/142/tn_14266.html).

However, I'd recommend using an up-to-date Flash Player, since new versions contain bug fixes and security patches. You can download Youtube video's through websites like [KeepVid](http://keepvid.com/), [Flash Video Downloader](http://www.flashvideodownloader.org/) and [SaveTube](http://www.savetube.com/).

Otherwise, use a Firefox add-on like [Flash Video Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader-youtube/)'s.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. Use the [DownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/) addon instead.